How to give AWS Rekognition permission to get object in S3 bucket?
I am trying to create an application in the cloud which uses S3, Lambda and Rekognition amongst others.
The problem i am having now is that i get the following error when running my Lambda:
An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the SearchUsersByImage operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
I tried googling, and asking chatgpt but it still doesn't work.
The services live in the same region (eu-central-1) and are created using cloudformation (SAM).
I added a role with a policy to my lambda function so it would be allowed to talk to S3, but it still doesn't work. This is what my role looks like (i shortened it a bit):
  ProcessEmployeeImageExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: RekognitionSearchUserByImagePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: rekognition:SearchUsersByImage
                Resource: !GetAtt EmployeeCollection.Arn
        - PolicyName: LambdaBasicExecutionPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility
                  - sqs:ChangeMessageVisibilityBatch
                  - sqs:DeleteMessage
                  - sqs:DeleteMessageBatch
                  - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
                  - sqs:ReceiveMessage
                Resource: !GetAtt ImagesQueue.Arn
        - PolicyName: S3ReadPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: s3:GetObject
                Resource: !GetAtt EmployeesArrivedImagesBucket.Arn

This is what my Lambda resource looks like:
  ProcessEmployeeImageFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Zip
      CodeUri: process_employee_image/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.12
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Role: !GetAtt ProcessEmployeeImageExecutionRole.Arn

When looking in the dashboard of my lambda function, it correctly shows that my lambda is allowed to talk to S3 but i still get the error.
I also used the AWS cli to use Rekognition. Using the cli everything works fine, so it doesn't have anything to do with my uploaded image.
So i think it has something to do with the fact that my lambda or my rekognition collection isn't allowed to talk to my s3 bucket?
Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Is the S3 bucket in the same region as the Rekognition endpoint that you are sending the API request to? Also, is the S3 object KMS-encrypted?

No it is not encrypted with KMS and everything is inside the same region.

but i think i accidentally stumbled upon the solution but still need to verify it. I changed this in my template.yaml.
        - PolicyName: S3ReadPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: s3:GetObject
                Resource: !Join
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                    - !Ref EmployeesArrivedImagesBucket
                    - /*

I added this and now it seems to work!

Ah, yes EmployeesArrivedImagesBucket.Arn is the bucket ARN so is not relevant to object-level permissions like s3:GetObject. That requires the ARN of the object(s).
